# Trying to scrape data from Github page

Tags: python, scrapy

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with this? I am trying to scrape the github page and store in a JSON file using the command "scrapy crawl gitrendscrape -o test.json". It creates the json file but its empty. I have tried to run the individual response.css file in scrapy shell. It's working perfectly over there. But for some reasons its not working in the spider. Can some please tell what is wrong? Thank you.

```
import scrapy


class gitrendscrape(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gitrendscrape"
    start_urls = [
        'https://github.com/google',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        toplanguages = response.css("div.simple-box a span.mr-2::text").extract()
        titles=response.css("div.org-repos li.col-12 div.d-inline-block a::text").extract()
        description=response.css("div p.col-9::text").extract()
        language = response.css("div.f6 span.mr-3::text").extract()  
        
        for ele in toplanguages:
            ele = ele.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()
        
        for ele in titles:
            ele= ele.encode('ascii','ignore').strip() 
        
        for ele in description:
            ele = ele.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()
        
        for ele in language:
            ele = ele.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()

        yield{
                'title': titles,
                'description':description,
                'language': language,
                'toplanguage': toplanguages,
        }

        next_page = response.css('div.paginate-container a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Here is the Terminal output of my spider.

```
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: gitrendscrape)
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'gitrendscrape.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'asd.json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['gitrendscrape.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'gitrendscrape', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'}
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-18 02:29:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-18 02:29:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://github.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-01-18 02:29:46 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://github.com/google>
2017-01-18 02:29:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-18 02:29:46 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 218,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1381,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 18, 9, 29, 46, 320372),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 18, 9, 29, 45, 755711)}
2017-01-18 02:29:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: What are the `for` loops in `parse` supposed to do? You continuously overwrite a local variable, but never save it anywhere.

Comment: The content that I scraping is in unicode format. So I convert it to string format. Without using a new variable.

Comment: `l = [1,2,3]; for x in l: x = str(x)` does not modify the original `l`. How is your code any different?

Comment: Oh, oh sorry, I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out. 

And I figured it out how to store it in JSON. 

scrapy crawl gitrendscrap -o test.json -t json. 

And a few changes here and ther, as Mikk suggested, it is ethically questionable, so I am not revealing it here how to do that, but yeah I got the answer from another thread in Stackexchange. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look more closely at your Debug info.

This line:

```
2017-01-18 02:29:46 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://github.com/google>
```

is telling you that `https://github.com/robots.txt` is forbidding you to crawl https://github.com/google. You're not allowed to do that because GitHub explicitly disallowed it. Scrapy crawlers, being good bots, obey robots.txt. There is a way to ignore robots.txt in scrapy, but I'm not going to tell you how to do it because it would be ethically questionable.

EDIT: I should point out that the robots.txt allows the following:

```
Allow: /*/*/tree/master
Allow: /*/*/blob/master
```

So you *could* try to crawl, e.g., https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/tree/master/, substituting `flexbox-layout` with the repo you want.

Alternatively, write to support@github.com or use the API as the robots.txt suggests.

Comment: Then how come when I run the same code or response.css line in scrapy shell, I can get the output? That time my content is there in the variables.